Unable to perform silent install
I am trying to install this file using silent install on cmd. Of course first I am using the 7zip to further extract the .exe file. This is creating a folder . In that folder I want to install dpinst-amd64.exe file silently. But no matter what I try, it asks me to press Next.
I was trying this ,
dpinst-amd64.exe /?
And clearly it shows all the commands that can be used.

So I try something like dpinst-amd64.exe /Q or dpinst-amd64.exe /S and it gives the same wants me to press Next. Please help.
Edit:
This I what I see when I run dpinst-amd64.exe /S

Then upon pressing Next, it gives me a license agreement page.

Upon accepting the license agreement, it installs the drivers and shows this.


Your screenshot doesn’t show that behavior

The software must support running silently in order to be run silently. Also, when the screen content you are trying to share is text, as your image is, copy the text and use the formatting tools in the post editor rather than including a screenshot. What is the message around when you must press Next? Please EDIT your post to clarify it.

Did you try using /SA, /SE, or /SW? The Help text says those are the switches for suppressing dialogs. Did you do any research regarding this besides checking the /help? Online others have asked this question and it appears a common issue is that the OS may not yet trust the certificate the package is signed using. It FEELS as though you're following some guide, because I don't see another reason you would've extracted the package. What guide(s) are you following? Have you imported the signing cert or did you get the package from Microsoft or your OEM?

I got the .exe package from the original site. https://ftdichip.com/drivers/vcp-drivers/ . I haven't imported any certificate as I guess its a genuine package from the vendor.
